# Histogram based search in SOLR (relevancy by position in multivalued field)

Tags: algorithm, search, solr, histogram

I'm trying to add histogram based search into SOLR. For instance, we need to search closest (or exact the same) distribution to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. So, most likely, we can use multivalued field of ints.

**The question is - how to make results more relevant depends on their position in multivalued field?**

For example

`[1, 2, 3, 5]` 
is more relevant to `[1, 2, 3, 4]` - only last element is different,
than

`[1, 4, 3, 2]`, despite a fact, that numbers in this example is exact the same, positions of 2 elements are different.

On the other hand, we don't need exact elements search, because we need to find just a closest one. The weight of elements is the same.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How many values are we talking about when indexing and when searching? Only exact matches (i.e. the distance from expected position does not matter)?

Comment: @MatsLindh Hi, it's up to 255 values at both stages, indexing and searching. Not only exact matches, but closest either.

Comment: But what's the definition of closest? Does the distance between position and expected position matter, (i.e. is `1 2 4 3` better than `1 4 3 2` because of the lower distance between expected and actual?)

Comment: @MatsLindh I meant closest by value, like 1 2 3 5 is closer to 1 2 3 4, than 1 4 2 3 (1 difference in 1st example, opposite 3 differences in second) It's like a set of independent elements. BUT 1 2 3 5 is closer to 1 2 3 4 than 1 2 3 6, because last element, that has difference, just closer by value..

Comment: @MatsLindh Actually I'm doing search for images by color distribution (RGB). For each of 3 base colors, I'm getting a number of pixels, that images contains. Maybe my approach is wrong, and you know better way? I have ~30k of images, and I have to organize search in this collection most similar image.